# GAE Python - 'Clamp' dates together into a 'tree' structure

Tags: python, google-app-engine, date, datetime

I need to break down a date in python into: year, month, day and time(hour).

I have a list of objects, each object has a date property:

```
startDate=db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

The date property containts, the year, the month, the day and the time all in one.

I wish to create a new nested list(dictionary) where:

Outer list- is a list of years(that are present in at least one of the input dates) -> inside each year a list of months(that are present during that year in at least one of the input dates)-> inside this days(same as with months - days present in the input list) -> Inside that a list of times(hours)... each our pointing to it's respective object.

I hope this is easily understood.

If I get the list bellow as input:

```
{obj1 -> (2000 Dec 18 9:00AM), obj2 -> (2000 Dec 19 1:00PM)}
```

It will clamp them together so I'll have

```
(2000) -> (Dec) -> {(18) -> (9:00AM) -> obj1 ,(19) -> (1:00PM) -> obj2}
```

I hope this makes sense..

Basically I have a lot of events with dates and I want to list them like this:

```
Year ->
Month(s) of interest->
Day(s) of interest->
(event times)
.
.
.

Another Year ->
Relevant Month(s) ->
Relevant Day(s) ->
(event times)
.
.
.
```

Instead of:

```
(Event1 : complete date & time) , (Event2 : complete date & time) , (event3 : complete date & time)
```

Thanks

Comment: So, what is the problem ? Where did you get stuck ?

Comment: I am new to Python, I was missing two parts of the puzzle, one is the answer GodMan provided and the other is how to break down the date into four parts(year, month, day and time)..

Comment: You might want to look into the `datetime` as well as `time` module in order to convert the time into the required format, and even splitting it into a struct-like format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class a: ## Using this class just to explain
    def __init__(self,y,m,d,t):
        self.y=y
        self.m=m
        self.d=d
        self.t=t


o1 = a(2000,12,18,9) ## Just assuming integers here. you can choose immutable objects here
o2 = a(2000,12,19,13)
o3 = a(2001,11,18,9)
o4 = a(2000,11,18,6)
o5 = a(2000,12,6,7)

l=[o1,o2,o3,o4,o5]


d={}

for o in l:
    if o.y not in d:
        d[o.y] = {}
    # print d
    if o.m not in d[o.y]:
        d[o.y][o.m]={}
    if o.d not in d[o.y][o.m]:
        d[o.y][o.m][o.d]={}
    if o.t not in d[o.y][o.m][o.d]:
        d[o.y][o.m][o.d][o.t]=o
```

You can try producing a better formatted output:

```
for k,v in d.items():
    for j,h in v.items():
        print k,j,h
```

I get output as:

```
2000 11 {18: {6: <__main__.a instance at 0x0232E9E0>}}
2000 12 {18: {9: <__main__.a instance at 0x0232E940>}, 19: {13: <__main__.a instance at 0x0232E990>}, 6: {7: <__main__.a instance at 0x0232EA08>}}
2001 11 {18: {9: <__main__.a instance at 0x0232E9B8>}}
```

Comment: @Arthur: There might be better ways to do this for sure. Just 1 thing required from your side:
Can you run this code on a huge data set using GAE and tell us how much time it takes so that we can bench mark a better answer?

Comment: I can randomize dates for a benchmark. but the code is used to create a tree for a very specifc / rare event.. more than 100 instances are unlikely and I'm sure anything under 1,000 will be fine since this runs in linear complexity, which is fine.. The original direction I had in mind (looking for matches) was far worse than this.

Comment: Well, as you have to cover all the records in the list at least once, the time complexity would be linear. But, the resultant dictionary that you are getting will reduce the ammortized complexity of the dict to O(1) in gradual runs.

Answer (score 0):

```
ytree = {}
for obj in objects :
  dt = obj.time_field
  year = dt.year
  month = dt.month
  day = dt.day
  hour = dt.hour

  if not ytree.get(year):
    ytree[year] = {}
  if not ytree[year].get(month):
    ytree[year][month] = {}
  if not ytree[year][month].get(day):
    ytree[year][month][day] = {}
  if not ytree[year][month][day].get(hour):
    ytree[year][month][day][hour] = []
  ytree[year][month][day][hour].append(obj.event_name)
```

Comment: I think you should create a dict for ytree[year][month][day][hour].

Reason: It is scalable. Just assume that Arthur wants to nest 1 more level in case the fields of datetime become greater than 4